# how to implement this symfony form, with a entity which has a array of entities?

Tags: symfony

i have a big problem with a symfony form. i need to do the following:

I want to generate a form for a entity, but this entity has a array of other entities which should be also added (if possible).

here is the data structure:
I hava a Entity called Foo (keeps a array of FooItems) and the a entity FooItems.

```
class Foo
{   
    {...}
    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $fooItems;
    {...}
```

now i need to build a form for this, the user can add one or more FooItems to the Foo. How to realise this?

Comment: why do you keep fooItems as a string? I suggest you should keep it as doctrine relation

Comment: we assume that i have dont this, how must the form look like in the formBuilder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Symfony's cookbook:

How to Embed a Collection of Forms
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store multiple form fields into a single string in the database instead of an one-to-many relation, you can also implement an `DataTransformerInterface` to convert the fields to a string and back.
Taka a look a `DateTimeToStringTransformer` which does it for the `DateType` form element